# The TextView below a ListView do not display. Why?

Tags: android, listview, textview

I placed a textview below a listview, and they are both in a linearlayout. But the textview do not display, I cannot figure out why. Can anybody give me some clue or instructions to debug this?

Comment: Please provide the relevant code.

Comment: Probably it has something to do on the LayOut, try to use a different one like table layout or relative layout you can look them up on google. Sometimes one of the controls hide behind the other.

Comment: provide code from your layout, by default linearlayout orientation is 'horizontal' make sure you have specified 'vertical'

Answer (score 6):

It is always safer to set the `layout_height` of your ListView as `fill_parent` and then set its `layout_weight` to 1.

Answer (score 1):

What about adding listview and textview in each linear layout. It's work for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/app_bg">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">
            <ListView 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/android:list" 
                android:scrollbars="none">
            </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TextView 
            android:text="" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/txtHeader">
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this can help!!